# .NET Core: How to merge nested one-to-many relations in dto

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

How could merge nested child entity in parent?

I have these three entities:

```cs
public class Faculty
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Expected results in `ResultDto` is:

```cs
public class ResultDto
{
    public Guid FacultyId { get; set; }
    public string FacultyName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I *assume* that `ResultDto` has `Faculty`'s Id and Name and all collected user of its groups, but your question isn't clear. You better show your first efforts trying to achieve what you want. That tends to explain more than words.

Comment: Note that this will duplicate users that are in more than 1 group per faculty. If you want them to be distinct it depends much on the exact EF version how doable that is.

Comment: @GertArnold This is not possible in application logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `SelectMany`:

```cs
var results = context.Faculties.Select(f => new ResultDto
{
    FacultyId = f.Id,
    FacultyName = f.Name,
    Users = f.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Users).ToList()
}
```

This will run in EF-core versions like 5 and 6, also in 3, but slightly less efficiently.